# How to read an expression that assigns a value that has && and || in javascript of qml?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

This is an assignment that's really strange to me.

I have a `PanelTextField` component on qml that was done by another person.

```
PanelTextField {
    text: devtype.linkedData !== undefined && (""+devtype.linkedData.value) || "<unavailable>"
}
```

This seems to be something that is done on all kinds of JavaScript, but how can i read this?

Answer (score 2):

You can read so: if `devtype.linkedData` not undefined then return cast `devtype.linkedData.value` as string else return `"<unavailable>"`

Test this:

```js
var a;
var text = a !== undefined && (""+a) || "<unavailable>";
console.log(text); // RESULT: text = "<unavailable>"
    
a = "test";
text = a !== undefined && (""+a) || "<unavailable>";
console.log(text); // RESULT: text = "test"
```

Answer (score -1):

`&&` and `||` have equal priority, so you should read it from left to right, it's the same as `(.... && ....) || ....`

Comment: Logical AND has  a *higher* precedence than logical OR: [MDN Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).